# SVG image not loading on IOS devices

Tags: html, css, image, web, svg

I published a website using the github domain, and it was working perfectly fine on any computer, however when I opened the website on different Iphones, the SVG image did not load, does anyone knows how to solve it?

[These are my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPZpP.png)

[And this is one of the SVG image files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2Y1c.png)

On my index.html file I have a div with a class that displays the image:

```
<style>

      .spacer {
        aspect-ratio: 960/300;
        width: 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
      }

      .layer1 {
        background-image: url("./layer1.svg");
      }

</style>
<body>

      <div class="spacer layer1"></div>

</body>
```

The image is displayed perfectly fine on computers and android devices, but it does not load on any IOS phones that I have tested.

How can I make it load on any device?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  If so I'm currently facing this I would love an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `background-size` before the `background-position`. Seems there is a bug related to this on some IOS devices: http://geoffmuskett.com/strange-bug-on-ios-svg-background-images-no-showing/

```
<style>

      .spacer {
        aspect-ratio: 960/300;
        width: 100%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        
      }

      .layer1 {
        background-image: url("./layer1.svg");
      }

</style>
<body>

      <div class="spacer layer1"></div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I just tried it and it still doesn't seem to be working, the problem is the same, it works for androids but not for iOS devices.